# redirect all routes with a prefix

Tags: angular, redirect, url-rewriting, routes

I am trying to rewrite routes in my angular 9 application where I currently have a url structure that looks like

```
old/login
old/forgotPassword
old/profile
```

etc.

I would like to redirect all routes that contain old to route that removes the "old" piece of the url e.g. `/login`

Is there a general way to accomplish this in my routing module?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `HttpInterceptor` and modify the request URL to remove `old`